# Print pdf file from iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, iframe

I am displaying a pdf file in by using iframe. I need to prine that pdf file only from that page.
I have written below script for printing on button click.

```
//print pdf file
    $("#btnPrint").click(function () {      
        window.frames["printf"].focus();
        window.frames["printf"].print();
    });
```

Its working fine in chrome. But giving error in firefox and IE.
In firefix, giving error like :**Error: Permission denied to access property 'print'**

In IE, giving error like: **SCRIPT65535: Invalid calling object**

I am not using any plugin for it. Please let me know how can i able to fix the issue?

Comment: Consider using `<object>` instead of `<iframe>`, [here's how](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18890500/1768303).

Comment: i think its a cross browser problem, b'coz in chrome i can print it

Answer (score -1):

Here I suggest you to pass div ID to this given function, It will help you to print the content of that div.

function PrintSummary(tableid) {

```
var tbl = document.getElementById(tableid);
if (tbl) {

    strPrintContent += tbl.innerHTML;

    var printWin = window.open("print.html", "printSpecial");
    printWin.document.open();
    printWin.document.write(strPrintContent);
    printWin.document.close();
    printWin.print();
}
```

}

Comment: print.html, i do not want to open it in another window. the  iframe is opening in popup. And want to print from there only without preview.

Comment: give it a try, It will not open another window, "print.html" is a page will be genrated on fly by java script and after showing printer setting and print button click it will be closed automatically. believe it will help you. I suggest you not to use iframe

Comment: iframe is my requirement, i have not used it for print. I have tried your solution. Its opening new tab for print with NaN page