# C# Open PDF with webbrowser component opens Adobe Reader ( NET 2.0 )

Tags: c#, pdf, adobe, webbrowser-control

I want to display a PDF in my Csharp Application.
To do that I use the webbrowser component.

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(@"http://www.fes.de/rechtsextremismus/pdf/Vom_Rand_zur_Mitte.pdf");
```

But instead of showing the PDF in the webbrowser control it opens Adobe Reader.
I tested my IE PDF plugin and all works fine there. Internet Explorer displays the PDF inside the Broweser.

Unfortunately I have to use .NET 2.0. With .Net 4 it works..

Is there a workaround for NET 2.0?

Comment: ok nevermind Net 4 doesn't work either

btw... 
os windows 7,
ide visual studio 2013 express

Comment: Try one of these techniques to load a PDF: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18890500/1768303