# JS Print pdf file

Tags: javascript

I try to print pdf file in javaScript.
I get the file's url from the server.

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
                document.body.appendChild(iframe);

                iframe.style.display = 'none';
                iframe.src = urlBaseImage + 'Report//' + result;
                iframe.focus();
                iframe.contentWindow.print();
```

But he give me empty page, I checked the url and it is really correct.
What Can I do?
Thanks!

Comment: Here is an answer to similar question, maybe this can help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472951/how-do-i-print-an-iframe-from-javascript-in-safari-chrome or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18888131/print-pdf-file-in-iframe-using-javascript-getting-one-page-only

Comment: Before attempting to print, does the PDF successfully load into the `<iframe>`? If you simply enter the PDF URL into the address bar of the broswer, is the PDF loaded as the page? If no to the previous two questions, then how are you confirming that the URL is correct? As a side note, as of Chrome 46, [`window.print()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/print) is blocked inside an `<iframe>` unless its `sandbox` attribute has the value `allow-modal`.

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239513/print-pdf-directly-from-javascript

Answer (score 2):

You can use this library, Print.js: http://printjs.crabbly.com/

It is very easy to print PDF files with it.

Just pass the PDF file url to the `printJS()` function;

For example:

`printJS('docs/my_pdf_file.pdf');`

Answer (score 0):

```
 function printDisclosureDocument() {
  var doc = document.getElementById('pdfDocument');
 if (doc == 'undefined' || doc == null) {
    var pdfbox = document.createElement('embed');
    pdfbox.type = 'application/pdf';
    pdfbox.src = 'ShowPDF.aspx?refid=' + $('#MainContent_hdnRefId').val();
    pdfbox.width = '1';
    pdfbox.height = '1';
    pdfbox.id = 'pdfDocument';
    document.body.appendChild(pdfbox);
 }

if (doc != null && doc != 'undefined') {
    //Wait until PDF is ready to print    
    if (typeof doc.print === 'undefined') {
      setTimeout(function () { printDisclosureDocument(); }, 500);
    } else {
      doc.print();
    }
 }
 else {
         setTimeout(function () { printDisclosureDocument(); }, 500);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.